# Turning on Trace Flag 460 does not give a better error message

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I have a large insert query with ends in an error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
> String or binary data would be truncated

After some research I tried using TRACE FLAG 460, using the command below:

```
INSERT... 
VALUES...
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 460);
```

This gave the same error as before, so I tried to turn on the flag on server-level, using the command below:

```
DBCC TRACEON(460, -1);
```

Again, no change in the output. But when I check the flagstatus it gives all the right information:

```
DBCC TRACESTATUS(460);

TraceFlag   Status  Global  Session
460         1       1       0
```

Does anyone have a clue how I can get Trace Flag 460 working? My server information is down below:

```
Edition: Developer Edition (64-bit)
ProductVersion: 14.0.2037.2
ResourceLastUpdateDateTime: 2020-11-02 21:20:26.783
ResourceVersion: 14.00.2037
BuildClrVersion: v4.0.30319
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked the [**documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)??

It clearly says:

> **Note**: This trace flag applies to SQL Server 2017 (14.x) **CU12 and higher** builds

Which means SQL Server 2017 has to have a build version number of **14.0.3045.24** or higher - which you don't seem to have.

So you'll need to install *at least* CU12 (or better yet: the latest CU22 - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56128) on your machine for this to work

See: [SQL Server 2017 build versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4047329-sql-server-2017-build-versions-346e8fcd-c07c-5eeb-e10b-e3411ba8d8dd) - for all the details about the official version numbers of SQL Server 2017 (and it's various CU's)

Comment: I had found that is has to be CU12, but couldn't find any buildnumbers which corresponded with CU12 or higher. Thanks for the information!

Comment: Although with all due respect, the documentation is pretty unreliable. E.g. the [docs for SQL **2016**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#:~:text=This%20trace%20flag%20applies%20to%20SQL%20Server%202017%20(14.x)%20CU12%20and%20higher%20builds.) also say "Note: This trace flag applies to SQL Server **2017** (14.x) CU12 and higher builds.", yet it's working this very minute on my SQL 2016 SP3. _Based on the documentation_, I'd expect it not to work on SQL 2016 at all.

Comment: @ReversedEngineer, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had read elsewhere on the internet, at https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/03/how-to-fix-the-error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated/ to be more specific, that this trace flag was also present in SQL Server 2016 SP2, but, like the OP, I could not get the trace flag to work.

Comment: Have this customer with SQL Server 2017 CU26 on Ubuntu, but enabling the trace flag 460 makes no effect at all :(
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU26) (KB5005226) - 14.0.3411.3 (X64)   Aug 24 2021 09:59:15   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS)